# Digitally signing an executable to prevent blocking by Symantec Endpoint

Tags: windows, windows-10, security

I recently installed [`context`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation) on a laptop for which I do not control the security policy. The laptop has symantec endpoint protection installed and when I try to run the `context` executable from the command line Symantec Endpoint Protection opens with this window:

[image]

As it turns out, I can simply allow the file and the executable works as expected. I would like to sign this program such that symantec does not pick it up as a security risk. I installed the Windows Software Development Kit with `signtool` and tried the following command:

`signtool sign /fd C:\context\tex\texmf-win64\bin\context.exe`

Unfortunately, I got an error:

> SignTool Error: The specified algorithm cannot be used or is invalid.

How can I sign the file without `signtool` throwing such an error? I've seen some stuff about `certreq` but I'm not sure if that's the way to go....

## EDIT

Based on @user1686's answer, and the [provided examples](https://github.com/pedrocaetanos/PS-code-sign) I did the following in powershell:

```
> $certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\currentuser\my `
>> -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" `
>> -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
>> -KeyLength 2048 `
>> -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" `
>> -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
>> -KeyUsage DigitalSignature `
>> -Type CodeSigningCert
> signtool sign /fd $certificate.getcerthashstring() $(where.exe context)
SignTool Error: The specified algorithm cannot be used or is invalid.
```

As you can see, I'm still getting the same error, but it looks like `New-SelfSignedCertificate` is successfully generating a digital certificate with a hash string I can apparently use...

Comment: You do know SEPM allows you to allow the hash of an executable file, right? I don't understand why you'd try to sign it and all that other stuff to prevent SEP from seeing it in the future. I see two options with one being that of allowing an exception of the exe via the SEPM server configs. Another option is to submit the file to Symantec and report as a false positive and allow them to confirm it's safe, etc. The will eventually send an update or signature definition or whatever and it'll not longer be flagged but this takes time; I have done it before successfully though on a false positive

Comment: But the point for bypassing SEP on the exe for the immediate need assuming you have many PCs and an SEPM server with policies and such for all your computers, you have make a file hash exception so it'll trust the hash of the specific file which should match if installing the same version on the same OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No digital signature that you can locally generate will be accepted by
Symantec Endpoint Protection.

The signature must to be one that is recognized by Symantec,
meaning a code-signing signature that was bought from a seller known
and trusted by Symantec.

One method for avoiding the message might be to contact the
Symantec Endpoint Protection administrator of your company and ask
to whitelist the `context` executable.

Answer (score 1):

Although not shown in signtool's help text, the `/fd` option actually takes a hash algorithm name, e.g. `/fd SHA256`. In your case, "C:\…\context.exe" is indeed not a valid algorithm name.

You may also need some other options:

- `/a` to make signtool auto-select a code-signing certificate. (This is assuming you *have* a code-signing certificate installed in certmgr.msc – if you don't, then you cannot sign things.)
- `/tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td SHA256` to attach a *timestamp* that allows the signature to remain valid even after your code-signing certificate expires.
- `/v` to make signtool more talkative about what it does.

---

If you do not have a code-signing certificate, there are 3 ways to obtain one:

- Valid world-wide: buy one from a certificate authority (check the usual places that sell TLS/HTTPS certificates). You don't need the more expensive "EV Code Signing" variant in this case, just the regular (but still expensive) non-EV one.
- Valid organization-wide: if the laptop is joined to a company's Active Directory (not Azure AD) domain, and if the company has AD Certificate Services available, try requesting one from there via `certmgr.msc` → Personal → All Tasks → Request New Certificate. Your admin may need to approve it. (If no templates show up in the list, means this option is not available.)
- Valid on the computer only: create a self-signed certificate and install it in the computer's "Trusted Publishers" section (not Trusted Root!). The `certreq` command is indeed one way to create a self-signed certificate, but that's a separate topic. ([This](https://github.com/pedrocaetanos/PS-code-sign) repository has examples.)

Comment: I would be very grateful if you would take a look at the edit to my original question, in which I attempted your third option of first obtaining a self-signed code-signing certificate, and then attempted to sign the problematic executable with it.

Comment: The third option requires you to generate a code signing certificate and install that certificate into the certificate store for your user. Did you do those two steps? I don’t believe the option 3 can be used since your machine is connected to an AD domain more than likely and you don’t have elevated permissions. Even if you do this there is no guarantee that your security software still won’t complain

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about installing the certificate into my certificate store. If option 3 is not possible then I don't know if its worth going through the trouble of generating my own digital signature. I've already filed a false-positive report with symantec and they state that they will respond within two business days. I also subscribed to the context mailing list to see whether they have other compiled binaries which are digitally signed....